# How to design classes to share their methods declarations in this specific case?

Tags: c#

I have class like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    const string Prefix = "ClassA";

    public string GetString([DataSource = Prefix + "string"] int id)
    {...}

    public int GetInt([DataSource = Prefix + "int"] int id)
    {...}
    ...
}
```

now I need to declare `ClassB` with `const string Prefix="ClassB"`, and `ClassC` with  `const string Prefix="ClassC"`, all the rest code is equal to `ClassA`. I know I can share methods implementation through base class, but there are like 30 other methods, differing by attribute value only: each class uses its own prefix, amount of methods and their signatures are always stay the same. That's why I'd like to share methods declarations also. Constants are not inheritable, class getters are not allowed to be used in attributes declarations. `[DataSource]` attribute is declared inside third-party lib and there is no way to update its code, and no other imperative ways offered to use Data Sources. Any ideas how to share the code? I'd like c# would have something like include directive to be able include same code snippets right into different classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would declare an interface containing all the methods these classes 'share', to be sure all classes have the same contract.

In order to deal with the attribute issues, I would use a [T4 template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to actually *generate* all classes from a single template.

Comment: T4 is good when you have a template and lots of dynamic data to insert in, in my case all resulted files will be equal except class name and one constant value. That's why I thought there must be a better solution, looks like .NET does not provide any good solution for this problem. If it's the only workaround, well, I'll use T4